# Best Case / Worst Case Recurrence Relations

Tags: recursion, code-analysis, recurrence

So, I have a psuedocode that I have to analyze for a class. I'm trying to figure out the best case and the worst case in terms of theta. I figured out the best case, but I'm having trouble with the worst case. I think the worst case is actually the same as the best case, but am second guessing myself and would like some feedback on how to properly develop the recurrence for the worst case if in fact they are not the same.

Code:

```
function max-element(A)
    if n = 1
        return A[1]
    val = max-element(A[2...n]
    if A[1] > val
        return A[1]
    else
        return val
```

Best Case Recurrence:

```
T(1) = 1
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 1

T(n) = T((n-2) + 1) + 1
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 -> T(n) = T(n-k) + k
Let k = n-1
T(n) = T(n-(n-1)) + n - 1
T(n) = T(1) + n -1
T(n) = 1 + n - 1
T(n) = n
```

Comment: Best and worst case are the same for your code. Both is in `Θ(n)` just as you calculated.

Answer (score 0):

The running time only depends on the number of elements of the array; in particular, it is *independent of the contents* of the array. So the best- and worst-case running times coincide.

A more correct way to model the time complexity is via the recurrence `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)` and `T(1)=O(1)` because the `O(1)` says that you spend some additional constant time in each recursive call. It clearly solves to `T(n)=O(n)` as you already noted. In fact, this is tight, i.e., we have `T(n)=Theta(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The running time only depends on the number of elements of the array; in particular, it is independent of the contents of the array. So the best- and worst-case running times coincide.

A more correct way to model the time complexity is via the recurrence T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1) and T(1)=O(1) because the O(1) says that you spend some additional constant time in each recursive call. It clearly solves to T(n)=O(n) as you already noted. In fact, this is tight, i.e., we have T(n)=Theta(n).